# calling a function from a class inside another function

Tags: python, django-models

I'm learning python/Django and I'm trying to code a shopping cart. there is a decrease_inventory(self, amount) that I need to call it in another section but it gives me a red underline of it and saying that this function is not defined and suggests to define it automatically, but I want to call that it from that class. 
do you think it happens because I write the "pass"? or there is a method to call a function from another class? Thank you so much for helping me.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_index=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    inventory = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def increase_inventory(self, amount):
        pass

        def decrease_inventory(self, amount):
            pass

        def __str__(self):
            return 'Type: {0} Price: {1}'.format(self.name, self.price)




class Order(models.Model):
    # Status values. DO NOT EDIT
    STATUS_SHOPPING = 1
    STATUS_SUBMITTED = 2
    STATUS_CANCELED = 3
    STATUS_SENT = 4


    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    total_price = Sum(F('amount') * F('product__price'))
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=status_choices)

    @staticmethod
    def initiate(cls, customer):
        return cls.objects.create(customer=customer, status=cls.STATUS_SHOPPING)

    def add_product(self, product, amount):
        self.status = self.STATUS_SHOPPING
        print(product.id)
        if self.orderrow_set.filter(product=product).exists():
            preexisting_order_row = self.orderrow_set.filter(product=product)
            preexisting_order_row.amount += amount
            if amount == 0:
                raise ValueError(
                    print('value must be bigger than 0')
                )
            if product.inventory < amount:
                raise ValueError(
                    print('cant buy more than shops inventory')
                )
            preexisting_order_row.save()
        else:
            new_order_row = OrderRow.objects.create(
                product=product,
                order=self,
                amount=amount,
            )

    def remove_product(self, product, amount=None):
        self.status = self.STATUS_SHOPPING
        try:
            preexisting_order_row = OrderRow.objects.get(product=product, order=self)
            if preexisting_order_row.amount > 1:
                preexisting_order_row.amount -= amount
                preexisting_order_row.save()
            else:
                preexisting_order_row.delete()
        except OrderRow.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    def submit(self):
        cart = OrderRow.objects.all()
        if cart.amount > Product.inventory & Order.total_price > Customer.balance:
            self.status = self.STATUS_SHOPPING
            raise ValueError(
                print('the amount you chose is bigger than inventory or you dont have enough money'))
        else:
            self.status = self.STATUS_SUBMITTED
            Customer.balance -= Order.total_price
            decrease_inventory()
            if self.STATUS_SUBMITTED:
                print('submit completed')
                self.save()
                self.STATUS_SHOPPING
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is `decrease_inventory()` also a method of another class and you want to call that function from the `submit()` method of `Product`, or are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: yes, decrease_inventory() is defined inside class Product and there is submit() where I want to call it. I edited the indention here! sumbit() is not inside th Product

Comment: Is `submit` defined in some other class, as it takes `self` as an argument?

Comment: yes, 'submit' is from 'Order' class. I didn't want to post all the codes, I thought it would become a very long post. should I edit it and add 'Order' part as well?

Comment: I can't tell without looking at your implementation of `class Order`, but I'm guessing it has some attribute that is a list of `Product` instances. If that is the case and you want to call `decrease_inventory()` on all of these instances, you could use a `for` loop. The main point is that `decrease_inventory()` must be called on some object, as it is not in the global namespace. If this is not the case, please post more of your code in order for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I have order_row, which the user adds the product into it, and when he/she submit the order_row, inventory decrease by the amount user bought. I edited the post. so, I should create a for loop which goes through all product in Order-row and decrease them?

Answer (score 0):

Use this for this problem.Call Method from class in other class

```
Product.decrease_inventory()
```

Comment: If you feel you have a helpful answer, provide some explanation as why this is correct, and the original went wrong. Of course with proper code formatting. This answer hangs in mid-air as does not explicitly relate to the code (not even where to put it).